# Windows Application doesn't start up on release

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, release

I have made a Windows Application that compiles and runs succsefully in debug mode but when put in release I am unable to start up de project from the bin folder or the published app in the destination folder.

It is compiling successfully in release mode.

The behavior is that when I double click on the app it tries to start but the window never opens.

Any idea what it might be?

Appreciate the help

Thanks

Comment: Call your release exe from a separate cmd window and you should see any exceptions thrown.

Comment: And by debug mode, do you mean through Visual Studio, or via the bin\debug folder? If you can run via bin\debug, are you able to see missing/extra files between the two directories?

Comment: google `remote debug`

Comment: There are four obviously possible ways to run this (there are more, but, 4 for now):. 1) A debug build run from the debugger, 2) A debug build run by double-clicking or from the command line, 3) A release build run from the debugger, 4) A release build run by double-clicking or the command line.  Your description sounds like you have tried 1 and 4.  Have you tried all 4 ways, in particular, starting a Release build with F5 from within VS?

Comment: Open the Windows Event Viewer and look for the error that happens after you start the application.

Comment: Your app.config in release config is not valid, or you don't have the proper .net framework installed (if running from another computer).

Comment: You can start inserting a try catch in your main: `int Main{try{// your actual code} catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex);}}` possibly, you will get a messagebox with some useful information

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I ran debug mode on both visual studio and bin/debug and they worked perfectly. However when double clicking on the application icon on the bin/release it just doesn't start up. I tried running it through the command line but I didn't get any exceptions

Comment: Im getting these errors in the Windows Event Viewer

Comment: Exception info: System.BadImageFormatException At program.Mainn() and also a faluting module name KERNELBASE.dll